# I am having difficulty understanding this pseudocode and converting it into a trace table

Tags: trace

I am just starting out in programming and have come across a question that confused me. 
I need to use this to fill out a trace table but I don't really understand what this pseudocode means

```
read in value of n
p ← true
for i is 2 to (n – 1)
 if( n MOD i = 0)
 p ← false
end if
end for loop
output p
```

here is a link to an image of the question
http://s15.postimg.org/517iinbmz/Psuedocode.png

Comment: What part do you understand and what part you don't understand? Perhaps you just don't understand the concept of "for"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple version of the pseudocode using a "simple" loop instead of "for".

```
read the value of n
set p to true
set i to 2
loop until i is equal to n-1
  if the module of n/i is equals to 0 //Basically checking if n is divisible by i
    set p to false
  endif
  increment i by 1 //Basically i = i + 1
endloop
output p
```

With this you should be able to figure out what the code is doing :) Not doing to tell you the answer because you should think and find the answer by yourself.

EDIT:
For clarification, you can see the for as a shortcut of the "while loop".
Basically you just set the iteration variable (i) to a initial value, start the loop, check if the stop condition is met and after every iteration you increment the iteration variable (i) by 1 (or by 2,3,4...,9999999999 :P).

So, in the example, for = "set i initial value to 2 then do the loop while i is different than n-1 and also increment the value of i by 1 every time you iterate"